# Propagation behaviour of transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-aop

I am using annotation based declarative approach for spring aop.
sample code

```
ClassA{
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
add()
{
method1();
method2();
method3();

}
}
```

But I have still doubt on use of propagation.does propagation.Requires_New means that each request will start new transaction.

Second question:

Does failure of any method like method2,method3 will cause the transaction to rollback?

I will be very happy if any can help me to leans transaction propagation.

can someone provide me a real world example where we need a participate in existing transaction.because I visualise that add function that we are using in above example will be independent for all users,or any other function will be independent to each user who is calling. I am not able to find example where other propagation behaviour like PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS ,PROPAGATION_MANDATORY,PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW etc. are used

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Answering this comment, not the actual question:

> transaction are session specific or
>   request specific – Vish 3 hours ago

Neither. request and session are both web-specific scopes, while the Spring Transaction abstraction has nothing to do with web technologies.

The scope of `@Transactional` is per method invocation, as `@Transactional` is implemented through Spring AOP. The transactional state is kept in `ThreadLocal` variables which are initialized when the outermost `@Transactional` method is entered and cleared with commit or rollback when it is left. This whole abstraction works on Java method level, and hence does not require or profit from a web container.

---

And in response to this Question in the comment below:

> thanks @sean,i am stil not able to get
>   answer where other propagation
>   behaviour like PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS
>   ,PROPAGATION_MANDATORY,PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW
>   etc are used. please refer above for
>   whole question

Here's the list of [`Propagation`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) values with my comments:

> **MANDATORY**
>   Support a current transaction, throw an exception if
>   none exists.

Does not start a new Transaction, just checks whether a transaction is active (must be inside either another `@Transactional` method call or a programmatically created transaction)

> **NESTED**
>   Execute within a nested transaction if a current transaction
>   exists, behave like
>   `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` else.

Start a nested transaction if a transaction exists, start a new transaction otherwise.

> **NEVER**
>   Execute non-transactionally, throw an exception if a transaction
>   exists.

Does not start a transaction. Fails if a transaction is present.

> **NOT_SUPPORTED**
>   Execute non-transactionally, suspend the current transaction if one
>   exists.

Does not start a transaction. Suspends any existing transaction.

> **REQUIRED**
>   Support a current transaction, create a new one if none
>   exists.

If a transaction exists, use that, if not, create a new one. **In 95% of cases, this is what you need.**

> **REQUIRES_NEW**
>   Create a new transaction, suspend the current transaction if one
>   exists.

Always creates a new transaction, no matter if an existing transaction is present. If there is, it will be suspended for the duration of this method execution.

> **SUPPORTS**
>   Support a current transaction, execute
>   non-transactionally if none exists.

Can use a transaction if one is present, but doesn't need one (and won't start a new one either)

---

In most cases, `REQUIRED` is what you need (hence it's the default in the `@Transactional` annotation). I have personally never seen any other value but `REQUIRED` and `REQUIRES_NEW` in use.

Comment: thanks @sean,i am stil not able to get answer where  other propagation behaviour like PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS ,PROPAGATION_MANDATORY,PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW etc are used. please refer above for whole question

Comment: Thanks @Sean.so if multiple request are invoking a same method say ADD(),REQUIRED annotation will make them to run in the same transaction??.but i think all the Add() method invocation will be  independent to each other in term of transaction..there is still a bit of confusion

Comment: @Vish No, never. A new request always means a new method invocation in a new thread and hence a new transaction. All of this transactional stuff happens within one method invocation, the outermost one. It gets tricky when the outer method calls an inner transactional method, but calling the outer method twice means two transactions, whether it's in a web context or not.

Comment: +1 Wonderful explanation. Could you please explain > The transactional state is kept in ThreadLocal variables which are initialized when the outermost @Transactional method is entered and cleared with commit or rollback when it is left.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd please explain difference between propagation NEVER and don't mark method  with Transactional at all

Comment: @gstackoverflow none. but since the annotation is inherited, you can use propagation=NEVER on method level to turn off transaction handling for individual methods

Comment: I didn't catch you. I cannot understood what you mean about annotation inheritance

Comment: @gstackoverflow if the class is annotated as `@Transactional` but you want to turn it off for individual methods

Comment: May i know what exactly meaning of  non-transactionally, as i am fresher

Answer (score 4):

Transaction propagation indicates what should be the behaviour of the given method when it is invoked. `REQUIRES_NEW` means that a new transaction should always be started, even if there is an ongoing transaction.

If `method1()`, for example, defines `REQUIRES_NEW`, than it will execute in a new transaction.

An exception will rollback the current active transaction, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Requires_New](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW) means that each request will start new transaction. and Yes failure in method2,method3 will cause the transaction to rollback, depending on the rollback properties.
check [Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) properties.

Comment: transaction are session specific or request specific